# Call a class using a respective strinig name

Tags: python, class

I have a registry as,

```
catalog_registry = {}
```

and my registry class is,

```
class Catalog:
   def __init__subclass__(cls):
      catalog_registry[cls.__name__] = cls
```

and i have some 4 classes and it may keep adding viz.,

```py
class CreateWithName(Catalog):
   @staticmethod
   def execute():
      ...

class CreateWithoutName(Catalog):
   @staticmethod
   def execute():
      ...
```

similarly i register all my classes
and i used mapping as,

```
catalog_names = {
"with Name": "CreateWithName",
"withour name": "CreateWithoutName"
}
```

and i call the classes as,

```
class_name = calatalog_names[name]
```

where name is the string i receive as input

so now i call it as,

```
result = catalog_registry.get(class_name).execute()
```

Here How can i call the class without using the dictionary mapping I added

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "call the class". What exactly do you want the result of the code to be, and why? For example, when you use the dictionary, and you end up with `class_name` being equal to the string `"CreateWithName"`, *why is that useful to you*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if the input i receive is "with Name", the i want to call class "CreateWithName" which will have some static method functions say execute
(i have edited my code, check now)

Comment: This can be done, but instead of doing that, why dont you simply put the classes in the dict, e.g. `{"with Name": CreateWithName, ...}`?

Comment: I did the dictionary method, but i need an alternate method may be something like a decorator or whichever looks neat

Comment: It would help if you explain the overall goal, i.e. the actual problem. I.e.: give examples of possible input to the program (and explain the source - from a file? The command line? Interactive input? Something else?), and exactly what you want to happen as a result